# Django strange behaviour of aggregation over custom ManyToMany field

Tags: django, database, django-aggregation

I've encountered some unexpected (for me) behavior of aggregation over `ManyToMany` field in django.

I have the following schema:

```
class ContestTaskRelationship(models.Model):
    contest = models.ForeignKey('Contest', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.ForeignKey('Task', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    solved = models.ManyToManyField('User', related_name='contests_tasks_solved', blank=True)
    cost = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Contest(models.Model):
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField('Task',
                                   related_name='contests',
                                   blank=True,
                                   through='ContestTaskRelationship')

class Task(models.Model):
    pass
```

Then I have one task and two contests, connected to that task. If I try to annotate count of `ContestTaskRelationship` models like that (assuming `contest` is one of the contests):

```
task = contest.tasks.annotate(number_solved=Count('contesttaskrelationship')).first()
```

I get `task.number_solved == 1`, but when I try like that:

```
task = Task.objects.filter(id=1).annotate(number_solved=Count('contesttaskrelationship')).first()
```

I get the expected result `task.number_solved == 2`. Why is that? Isn't it the same object and the same field?

**UPD**: I found out that in the first example additional condition is added to query, the `contest_id` is compared to the `id` of corresponding contest. Is it documented somewhere? I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score -1):

When you write this code:

```
Task.objects.get(id=1)
```

you will get the Task instance, and it seems that there is method named 'annotate'  with 'number_solved' argument in your Task model. You cannot do any annotate after some queryset methods: get, count, aggregate, last, first, exists and may be some more. This methods do not return queryset.

If you want to see the query, and compare it.

You can do two things:

1. print(Contest.objects.all().query)  # return raw query to db
2. install django-extensions and use this command to add shell:

   ```
   ~# python manage.py shell_plus --print-sql
   ```

if you see the query you can compare it and solve this problem by yourself